# FullCalendar v5 custom font and background colors of multi-day events

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a FullCalendar v5 `classNames` question.  I have a [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sevenreeds/wf5soq8L/33/).  The events in the fiddle are static but are pulled from a recent run of the live calendar with some ID info edited.

Notice the events that span over a day boundary.  The font is white, it should be black.  The colors for font and background are set in a series of classes that I add to the events based on circumstance.  The events that span day boundaries do not seem to play by the same rules.

Is there something else I should do to custom style multi-day events?

Thanks

Comment: N.B. It's not necessary to write `.addClass("fc fc-media-screen fc-direction-ltr fc-theme-bootstrap");` in your code - fullCalendar adds these classes to the element automatically.

Comment: Looking at the element inspector in the JSFiddle we can see that the containers for the multi-day events have the class `fc-h-event` added additionally which isn't there on the others. This causes a rule `var(--fc-event-text-color,#fff)` to be applied to set the event text colour, and this seems to override the colour you've set in your class. I'm not quite sure how to override this atm, will give it some thought if I can, as perhaps could you in the meantime.

Comment: Ah, thanks on the `addClass` advice.  I was taking that from the FC active demo.  I assumed it was necessary. Thanks also for the text color class advice. I will look at tweaking that. cheers

Comment: @ADyson question. I have been trying to manipulate the classes. For example: after `calendar.render();` do a jquery `find` on `div.fc-event-main` and remove that class everywhere. Either the search fails or maybe the DOM hasn't settled. when should this kind of search happen in the process? I've also tried it in one of the render hooks.

Comment: Please ask a brand new question about it and post your exact code. Then it will be clearer, and also others have a chance to help as well as me. Thanks.